# VB.net Autocomplete Textbox filter using mysql database as custom source

Tags: mysql, vb.net, autocomplete

I'm Having a problem regarding to the autocomplete textbox. First I already made the autocomplete textbox work with mysql database as custom source but the default textfilter of autocomplete is "start with" not "contains". I want to change the textfilter to "contains", so that when I search any part of the string, the whole name which contains the searched word will appear in the autocomplete suggestions.

Can anyone help me fix my code?

This is the code i've done so far:

```
            txtSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            txtSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            Dim DataCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
            Dim query As String
            sqlcon = New MySqlConnection
            sqlcon.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=svfmemberlistdb"

            Try
                sqlcon.Open()
                query = " SELECT Name FROM svfmemberlistdb.svfmemberlist "
                sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, sqlcon)
                sqladr.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
                sqladr.Fill(ds)
                sqladr.Dispose()
                sqlcon.Close()
                For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                    If row.ToString.Contains(txtSearch.Text) Then
                        DataCollection.Add(row(0).ToString())
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = DataCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

I quote here Mitja Bonca's answer on MSDN.

> In this case, autocompletemode will just not do. Its code is not meant
>   for something like it.
>
> You will have to do your own code, to do the filtering on each letter
>   press.
>
> So I would suggest not to use autocompletemode, and get all the data
>   (names) into dataTable. When user presses some button ("1" for
>   example), you start with your filtering, by creating new Datatable
>   (leave the main one untached - so you can return back to all data when
>   clearing comboBox by backspace), with Copy() method - to create a full
>   copy of original one, and use Select method to do the filteing.
>
> This should look something like by using % simbol on both sides of a
>   string - to filter inbetween - this is what you want!

```
DataTable AllNames = new DataTable();
//fill it up and leave it untouched!

//to filter comboBox with names that contains pressed characters do in 
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    string name = string.Format("{0}{1}", comboBox1.Text, e.KeyChar.ToString()); //join previous text and new pressed char
    DataRow[] rows = table.Select(string.Format("FieldName LIKE '%{0}%'", name));
   DataTable filteredTable = AllNames.Clone();
   foreach(DataRow r in rows)
       filteredTable.ImportRow(r);
   comboBox1.DataSource = null;
   comboBox1.DataSource = filteredTable.DefaultView;
   comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FieldName";
}
```

[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ebaaed0-cd29-4663-9a43-973729d66cea/autocomplete-combobox-match-any-part-of-string-not-only-beginning-string?forum=winforms)

EDIT: This is of course a `c#` answer not `VB.NET` but it might be helpful to get the concept.